# Ruby - Convert Nested Hash to CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

I currently have an object (failure_object) with the following structure:

{"2020-08-25"=>{"adwords"=>8, "analytics"=>69, "bing"=>5, "dfa"=>3, "doubleclick"=>2, "getstat"=>2}, "2020-08-26"=>{"adwords"=>22, "bing"=>7, "dfa"=>4, "doubleclick"=>6, "getstat"=>2}, ...

I am looking to write this to a CSV with the following columns:

+------------+--------------+-------------+
|     A      |       B      |      C      |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2020-08-25 | adwords      | 8           |
| 2020-08-25 | analytics    | 69          |
| 2020-08-25 | bing         | 5           |
| 2020-08-25 | dfa          | 3           |
| 2020-08-25 | doubleclick  | 2           |
| 2020-08-25 | getstat      | 2           |
| 2020-08-26 | adwords      | 22          |
| 2020-08-26 | bing         | 7           |
| 2020-08-26 | dfa          | 4           |
| 2020-08-26 | doubleclick  | 6           |
| 2020-08-26 | getstat      | 2           |
+---+--------+--------------+-------------+

My experience of writing ruby with respect to outputting to csv has so far only covered arrays,a and though I can convert this hash object to an array, the relationship between the key value pairs is not retained in the way I desire.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If the lines `+---+--------+--------------+-------------+` are not to be written to the CSV file, you should remove them. If the field separator is a pipe (`|`) you should write `2020-08-25|adwords|8` rather than `| 2020-08-25 | adwords | 8 |`. To avoid confusion you need to show the exact image of the CSV file. Also, make you hash a complete Ruby object that corresponds to the image of the file you show (i.e., no `...`). That is general advice for any question you may ask.

Comment: It's also helpful to assign a variable to each input (e.g., `h = { "2020-08-25"=>{...}`) so that readers can refer tro that variable (`h` in my example) in answers and comments without having to define it.

Comment: @max : The desired output you show is not a valid CSV file. Aside from this, devide the problem into two steps: (1) Convert your hash into an array of arrays of strings, holding the data like you need them to be shown in the resulting file, (2) Convert this array into CSV (or whatever format you need). If you get stuck in one of these steps, ask a separate question for exactly this subproblem.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {
  "2020-08-25"=>{ "adwords"=>8, "analytics"=>69, "bing"=>5, "dfa"=>3,
                  "doubleclick"=>2, "getstat"=>2 },
  "2020-08-26"=>{ "adwords"=>22, "bing"=>7, "dfa"=>4, "doubleclick"=>6,
                  "getstat"=>2 }
}
```

---

When writing CSV files from objects other than CSV objects (obtained when reading a CSV file that is to be altered, for example), there is no particular advantage to using CSV methods. Here we could write the following.

```
COL_SEP = '|'
fname = 'tmp.csv'

File.open(fname, 'w') do |f|
  f.puts 'A|B|C'
  data.each { |date,h| h.each { |k,v| f.puts [date,k,v].join(COL_SEP) } }
end
```

Let's check that:

```
puts File.read(fname)
A|B|C
2020-08-25|adwords|8
2020-08-25|analytics|69
2020-08-25|bing|5
2020-08-25|dfa|3
2020-08-25|doubleclick|2
2020-08-25|getstat|2
2020-08-26|adwords|22
2020-08-26|bing|7
2020-08-26|dfa|4
2020-08-26|doubleclick|6
2020-08-26|getstat|2
```

See [File::open](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/File.html#method-c-open). By using `open` with a block the file is automatically closed after writing it. Had I written `f = File.open(fname, 'w')`, I would have needed to (remember to) close the file with `f.close` after having written it.

See also [IO#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-puts). `puts` should be used instead of [IO#write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-write) because it adds a line terminator. Recall that `File` is a subclass of `IO` (`File.superclass #=> IO`) so `File` inherits `IO`'s methods.

To create the same file using CSV methods one could write the following.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open(fname, 'w', col_sep: COL_SEP) do |csv|
  csv << ['A', 'B', 'C']
  data.each { |date,h| h.each { |k,v| csv << [date,k,v] } }
end
  #=> <as above>
```

As you see, it's little different to use CSV methods. See [CSV::open](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open).